# Wrap woocommerce shop/category page title in div

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently trying to wrap the page title on woocommerce shop & category pages into a `div` only with hooks. I do not want to overwrite any template files.

I've already tried using the hook `woocommerce_page_title` like this

```
add_filter('woocommerce_page_title', 'my_woocommerce_page_title');

    function my_woocommerce_page_title($title)
    {
        return "<div>" . $title . "</div>";
    }
```

which results in the following (because the `h1` is in the `wc-template-functions.php` file):

```
<h1 class="page-title"><div>Category</div></h1>
```

What I actually want to achieve is this:

```
<div><h1 class="page-title">Category</h1></div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `h1` in the location you mentioned is wrapped into `if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) )` – so I guess you would have to hook into _that_ filter first, and make it return false, to suppress generation of this `h1` completely - and then add your desired HTML output for the title using the next hook that gets processed in that same file, which is `woocommerce_archive_description`. But inside your handler function for the latter, you will have to fetch the title yourself, you won’t get it passed in as $title automatically any more.

Comment: Yes, i know where that `h1` comes from, as mentioned above – but I don't really know how to remove it without touching the template file :)

Comment: Hook into `woocommerce_show_page_title`, so that that will return false, so that the whole if condition is not true any more, so that is what inside the if does not get executed/putput to begin with.